# Android: How to use viewbinding in base class and migrate from kotlin synthetics

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

With the deprecation of `kotlin synthetics` I faced the problem, that I can not access some standard layouts from my `base class` anymore. For example, I have a base class for three fragments and in all of them, there is a button. My old approach was to get the button in the base class with synthetics and then assign some default clicklistener etc.

My question is: What would be the best approach to migrate from the synthetics to viewbinding / databinding here? Another question I am asking my self is, how could I access the view_layouts outside the activity / fragment now?

### Base class

```
abstract class BaseRebuildFragment(layout: Int) : Fragment(layout) {
    abstract val nextFragment: NavDirections
    abstract val baseViewModel: ViewModel
    open val dataOverViewFragment: Boolean = false
    @Inject @RebuildProgressDescription lateinit var progressBarDescription: ArrayList<String>

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initAppStandardToolbar()
        initStateProgressBar(progressBarDescription)
        initButton()
        hideBottomNav()
    }

    private fun initButton() {
        calibrate_btn_next.setOnClickListener { // not working anymore
            if (dataOverViewFragment) return@setOnClickListener else if (this.validForm()) findNavController().navigate(nextFragment)
        }
    }

    open fun validForm(): Boolean { return false }
}
```

### Fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RebuildOptionFragment : BaseRebuildFragment(R.layout.fragment_rebuild_option) {
    override val baseViewModel: RebuildViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_send_rebuild) { defaultViewModelProviderFactory }
    private val rebuildBinding: FragmentRebuildOptionBinding by viewBinding()
    override val nextFragment: NavDirections = RebuildOptionFragmentDirections.actionRebuildOptionFragmentToRebuildUserDataFragment()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        bindObjects()
        baseViewModel.setStateEvent(RebuildStateEvent.GetPrice)
        subscribeRebuildListObserver()
    }

    private fun bindObjects() = with(rebuildBinding) {
        viewModel = baseViewModel
        lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        lendingListener = LendingSwitch()
    }

    override fun validForm(): Boolean = baseViewModel.shippingValidator.isShippingOptionsValid()
}
```

### Accessing view outside of activity / fragment in utils package

```
fun Fragment.initStateProgressBar(progressBarDescription: ArrayList<String>) = with(app_standard_progress_bar) { // not working anymore
    setStateDescriptionData(progressBarDescription)
}

fun Fragment.initAppStandardToolbar() {
    toolbar.setupWithNavController(findNavController(), AppBarConfiguration(findNavController().graph)) // not working anymore
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById` can be used directly instead of using synthetics to accomplish the same thing, but without type safety. You have to provide the type since it won't be able to infer the type.

```
fun Fragment.initStateProgressBar(progressBarDescription: ArrayList<String>) = with(requireView().findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.app_standard_progress_bar)) { 
    setStateDescriptionData(progressBarDescription)
}
```

Comment: Are there any **big** performance disadvantages when using this approach? And it always says to me `Unresolved reference: FindViewById`

Comment: Not for this use case, since you are only calling it once for the activity or fragment. The synthetic properties use findViewById under the hood the first time you call them anyway. You would want to avoid using it repeatedly in a list like using it in onBindViewHolder in a RecyclerView, because then it could become perceivable. See the updated code above, I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

With view binding you're meant to inflate the layout yourself using the generated binding class - so for `R.layout.fragment_rebuild_option` it should be `FragmentRebuildOptionBinding`.

In `onCreateView`, call the `inflate` option on that class:

```
binding = FragmentRebuildOptionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
// return the root layout view
return binding.root
```

That creates a binding object that has all your `View` references as properties, like you get with synthetics - so things like `binding.calibrate_btn_next`. That means `binding` needs to be a member variable in your `Fragment` class, so all your functions can access it.

Then it's basically just a case of changing all your code to refer to `binding.whatever` instead of just `whatever`

Comment: The challenge in the OP’s case is that this function is common to all fragments, each of which will have a different binding class.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Exactly

Comment: Oh I see, yeah - I think the issue is synthetics is kinda dynamically typed almost, so you can get away with referring to things that aren't guaranteed to be in the layout you've passed in. View Binding is more like static typing, with all the restrictions that enforces (and more - they didn't even include ``inflate`` in the ``ViewBinding`` interface!) You might need to mess around with Data Binding instead, setting common variables in the layouts (like a click listener) and setting those dynamically: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#advanced_binding

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic views accessed without any certainty of type safety, you can use `findViewById` as you normally would have.

To access the view in a Fragment, you can use `requireView()`.